# Customizing heatmap colorbar and adding legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, heatmap

On my heatmap using Matplotlib to display different scores of animals across different days, X-axis represents days, Y-axis animal ID's, and the value in each cell signifies score. Time points with no available data I've denoted NaN (Not a Number).

NaN values in the heatmap are assigned a color using np.nan values. I want to represent empty values in two separate colors: one for time points before, another for after culling. How can I do this? I can give one color for all NaN values but want two different colors. I am okay with two different variables for two different values.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Load the data from the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("WB_1.csv")

# Step 1: Replace "NA" with pandas' NA representation
data = data.replace('NaN', pd.NA)

# Step 2: Set the pig IDs as the index and remove any empty rows or columns
data = data.set_index(data.columns[0])
data = data.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
data = data.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

# Generate the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8)) # Adjust the figure size as needed

# Define the colormap for valid data points (YlGnBu) and the color for NaN values (grey)
cmap_valid = cm.OrRd # You can choose a different colormap for valid data points
cmap_valid.set_bad(color='lightgrey') # Set NaN values to be displayed in grey

# Plot the heatmap using Seaborn with the specified colormaps
sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap_valid, annot=True, cbar_kws={'label': 'Log 10 viral load (Mean CN/mL)'},
            annot_kws={'size': 8}) # Adjust the 'size' value as needed for font size

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel("Days After Virus Challenge")
plt.ylabel("Animal IDs")
plt.title("Viraemia in Whole blood Post challenge")

# Display the heatmap
plt.show()
```

NaN NC Both.csv (read with `data = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/76995150/7758804')[0]`):

| Day 0 | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Day 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NC | NC | 0 | nan | nan |
| 0 | NC | NC | nan | nan | nan |
| 0 | NC | NC | 6.26601 | 5.93792 | 5.4236 |
| 0 | NC | 0 | 6.59106 | 5.96897 | 4.44071 |
| 0 | NC | 0 | 6.99108 | 5.8227 | 5.47374 |
| 0 | NC | NC | nan | nan | nan |
| 0 | NC | NC | 6.46392 | 5.93981 | 5.99807 |
| 0 | NC | NC | 5.88117 | 5.03937 | 4.0122 |

NaN only.csv (read with `data = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/76995150/7758804')[1]`):

| Day 0 | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Day 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | nan | 0 | nan | nan |
| 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 0 | nan | nan | 6.26601 | 5.93792 | 5.4236 |
| 0 | nan | 0 | 6.59106 | 5.96897 | 4.44071 |
| 0 | nan | 0 | 6.99108 | 5.8227 | 5.47374 |
| 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 0 | nan | nan | 6.46392 | 5.93981 | 5.99807 |
| 0 | nan | nan | 5.88117 | 5.03937 | 4.0122 |